# Thunderbird search on server seems broken: How to debug IMAP conversation?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I search in my IMAP folder Archive/2016 for the term "foo". There are several messages containing this word, but the search (ctrl-shift-f) tells me that there are not messages with this word in the body.

I use "search on server".

This looks like the IMAP server does return the wrong results.

How can I debug this?

Is there a way in thunderbird that I can see the IMAP commands that get send to the server and the responses which I get?

Since the communication is encrypted wireshark does not help :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you suspect the IMAP server is giving you the erroneous output, why don't you test it from command line and see for yourself?

Establisth a TLS connection with the IMAP server:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect imap.server.com:993
```

Log in and go to your inbox:

```
>>a1 LOGIN username password
<<a1 OK Logged in.
>>a2 SELECT INBOX
<<a2 OK [READ-ONLY] Select completed.
```

Search the body of your inbox messages for "foo"

```
>>a3 SEARCH BODY foo
<< [search results]
<<a3 OK Search completed.
```

Refer to [IMAP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1730) for additional commands. You didn't specify your OS, but `openssl` builds exist for most of them.

Comment: Nice, I can speak German, English and a bit French. Now I can talk IMAP. Thank you. Works good for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup https://www.stunnel.org on your host so it connects to real IMAPS (TLS) server, and then configure thunderbird to make unencrypted IMAP connection to localhost port on which `stunnel` listens. After that you can use wireshark to sniff localhost traffic, and see it unencrypted.